# Tensorflow gradient tape returns None for all variables

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to adapt the tensorflow text generation tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_generation) to using a simple gan akin to (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan)

Even when completely ignoring any new logic I might introduce into the "train step" method, the generator_tape will always return [None, None, None, None, None, None]

```
     with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
          generated = generator(input_0, training=True)
    
          real_output = discriminator(input_1, training=True)
          fake_output = discriminator(generated, training=True)
    
          gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
          disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)
    
        gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
        gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)
    
        generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
        discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
```

The discriminator, however, has all gradients tracked correctly.

The generator from the text generation tutorial is defined like this:

```
class GeneratorModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units):
    super().__init__(self)
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   stateful=False)
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

  def call(self, inputs, states=None, return_state=False, training=False):
    x = inputs
    x = self.embedding(x, training=training)
    if states is None:
      states = self.gru.get_initial_state(x)
    x, states = self.gru(x, initial_state=states, training=training)
    x = self.dense(x, training=training)

    if return_state:
      return x, states
    else:
      return x
```

Also watching all tensors, as well as generator.trainable_variables manually does not change the outcome.

I've seen that a non-differentiable loss function can sometimes be an issue. But given that it's from the dcgan tutorial, that should not be an issue.

Full code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import time
from tensorflow.keras import backend


fullPath = os.path.abspath("./" + 'input.txt')

# Read, then decode for py2 compat.
text = open(fullPath, 'rb').read().decode(encoding='utf-8')
# length of text is the number of characters in it
print(f'Length of text: {len(text)} characters')
# Take a look at the first 250 characters in text
print(text[:250])
# The unique characters in the file
vocab = sorted(set(text))
print(f'{len(vocab)} unique characters')

example_texts = ['abcdefg', 'xyz']

chars = tf.strings.unicode_split(example_texts, input_encoding='UTF-8')

ids_from_chars = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=list(vocab), mask_token=None)

ids = ids_from_chars(chars)

chars_from_ids = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary(), invert=True, mask_token=None)

chars = chars_from_ids(ids)

tf.strings.reduce_join(chars, axis=-1).numpy()

def text_from_ids(ids):
  return tf.strings.reduce_join(chars_from_ids(ids), axis=-1)


all_ids = ids_from_chars(tf.strings.unicode_split(text, 'UTF-8'))

ids_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_ids)



seq_length = 100

sequences = ids_dataset.batch(seq_length + 1, drop_remainder=True)


def split_input_target(sequence):
    input_text = sequence[:-1]
    target_text = sequence[1:]
    return input_text, target_text

dataset = sequences.map(split_input_target)

# Batch size
BATCH_SIZE = 64

# Buffer size to shuffle the dataset
# (TF data is designed to work with possibly infinite sequences,
# so it doesn't attempt to shuffle the entire sequence in memory. Instead,
# it maintains a buffer in which it shuffles elements).
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000

dataset = (
    dataset
    .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
    .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))

# Length of the vocabulary in StringLookup Layer
vocab_size = len(ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary())

# The embedding dimension
embedding_dim = 256

# Number of RNN units
rnn_units = 1024

print(tf.config.list_physical_devices())

discriminator = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])

discriminator.summary()

class GeneratorModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units):
    super().__init__(self)
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   stateful=False)
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

  def call(self, inputs, states=None, return_state=False, training=False):
    x = inputs
    x = self.embedding(x, training=training)
    if states is None:
      states = self.gru.get_initial_state(x)
    x, states = self.gru(x, initial_state=states, training=training)
    x = self.dense(x, training=training)

    if return_state:
      return x, states
    else:
      return x

generator = GeneratorModel(
    vocab_size=vocab_size,
    embedding_dim=embedding_dim,
    rnn_units=rnn_units)

for input_example_batch, target_example_batch in dataset.take(1):
    example_batch_predictions = generator(input_example_batch)
    print(example_batch_predictions.shape, "# (batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)")

generator.summary()

# This method returns a helper function to compute cross entropy loss
cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    real_loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output)
    fake_loss = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output), fake_output)
    total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
    return total_loss

def generator_loss(fake_output):
    return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(fake_output), fake_output)

generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()


checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=generator_optimizer,
                                 discriminator_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer,
                                 generator=generator,
                                 discriminator=discriminator)


checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_prefix,
    save_weights_only=True)

EPOCHS = 10

# Notice the use of `tf.function`
# This annotation causes the function to be "compiled".
#@tf.function
def train_step(input):

    input_0, input_1 = tf.unstack(input)
    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
      gen_tape.watch(generator.trainable_variables)
      generated = generator(input_0, training=True)

      #training discriminator with correct sequences
      real_output = discriminator(input_1, training=True)

      # training discriminator with generated sequences
      generated_indices = []
      for i in range(len(generated)):
          sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(generated[i], num_samples=1)
          sampled_indices = tf.squeeze(sampled_indices, axis=-1)
          generated_indices.append(sampled_indices)

      generated_indices = tf.stack(generated_indices) #create proper tensor
      fake_output = discriminator(generated_indices, training=True)

      gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
      disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))

def train(dataset, epochs):
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    start = time.time()

    for batch in dataset:
      #print(batch)
      train_step(batch)


    # Save the model every 5 epochs
    if (epoch + 1) % 15 == 0:
      checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)

    print ('Time for epoch {} is {} sec'.format(epoch + 1, time.time()-start))

train(dataset, EPOCHS)
```

Comment: cannot reproduce, please share the whole code you are using, the error does not seem to be here

Comment: In case it is relevant: I currently use tf 2.9.0

Comment: Full code now in question as well

Comment: The gradient disconnects at the sampling step `sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(generated[i], num_samples=1)`.

Comment: Thanks.

Any idea how I can fix that?

I tried tf.map_fn, but that has issues due to the mapping from float64 to int64 and

```
tf.stack([categorical_sampling(elem) for elem in tf.unstack(generated)])
```

instead of the other for loop seems to have the same effect.

Comment: From what I can see the issue is that no matter what, tf.random.categorical returns int64, however gradients can't be tracked for ints, is that right?

Sadly that also means I see no way of resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

As reported by [@bui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8990644/bui), the problem is this line right here:

```
sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(generated[i], num_samples=1)
```

However, you might be missing something IMO... in particular, the last layer of your generator is the following:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
```

which not redefining the activation function, is a linear layer, which is not the best in your case, since I suppose that you want a distribution `p(y|x)`

Given this, I don't also quite understand what are you trying to do with the GRU layer, since seems to me that you are doing a classification more than a generation...

However, you probably can solve all of your problems just removing the incriminated line, and use the generator output directly as the discriminator input

Comment: Even completely removing the for loop (which is necessary without sampling) doesn't fix the problem.  


Also directly feeding the generated data into the discriminator doesn't really make sense, given that the generator outputs probabilities for each character, meanwhile the discriminators other input obviously has to be actual text.  


As per missing: Yes, this is basically the rnn-text tutorial up until fit is called. The generator remains unchanged from that.  


Afterwards there'd usually still be sampling, but that wasn't quite necessary here imho.

Comment: @KENGURU if you need discrete sampling, you have to use the reinforce algorithm, because the derivative of your discrete sampling is 0 almost always, but it's expectation is not, so you can use the expectation estimated with Monte Carlo methods to get your gradient

Comment: @KENGURU also, `discriminator(generated_output)` in theory should work fine

Comment: I'll look into the sampling .

I do still not get why the generated_output in the discriminator should be fine though?

A discriminator that discriminates between characters lists and lists of probability distrbutions seems quite pointless? (Not to mention, as I said, directly doing that, without any sampling, still results in gradients = None)

Comment: @KENGURU because usually the words are one hot encoded based on your vocab size, thus a probability distribution is as meaningful as a one hot encoding vector (thus your decoder in theory should receive the one-hot encoded version of your phrase)

Comment: Fair, with onehot encoding that would make sense.

This still uses the default integer ID encoding via layers.StringLookup from the text generation tutorial though.

Comment: @KENGURU that's a problem, usually in GAN the "preprocessing" is done beforehand, in order to make everything differentiable (obv string lookup are not)... you can easily create 2 models, model1 with all the discriminator (no string lookup), and model2 which is stringlookup+model1, so that the weights are shared and you can have both versions, and then use the one that is best suited